# Python 3 input loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  use the `for` loop to input the `n` words

```
n = int(input(""))
for i in range(n):
    a = input("")
    print(a)
```

when I input:

```
3
1
1
1
2
```

It allow me to input the `n+1` words

And the `n+1` word can not be output

I just want to output n words then equal with the syntax in `C`:

```
int a = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d",&a);
```

[Update]

Actually it is a problem with Pycharm. And I don't know why.

In terminal,the code can work.

So,plz not downvote....

Comment: That code works correctly for me. How are you running it? Are you running it in the terminal or inside an IDE? Pass a prompt string to `input`, eg `input("> ")` to verify that it _is_ actually `input` that's accepting the n+1th word.

Comment: Your C code does not write anything to the output.

Answer (score 1):

It ran exactly 3 times when I tried it.
If you want to make it more explicit what you're doing you could set it to `for i in range(0,n):` but that won't really change anything.

The loop `for i in range(n):` will run from 0 to n-1.
So if you put in 3 it, it will generate 3 runs, with the values of `i` being 0, 1, 2.

```
n = int( input( "Enter the number of runs: " ) )
for item in range( 0, n ):
    a = input( "\tPlease Input value for index %d: "%item )
    print( a )
```

It generated the output:

```
Enter the number of runs: 3
    Please Input value for index 0: 1
1
    Please Input value for index 1: 1
1
    Please Input value for index 2: 1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this isn't working for you. Try this modified version that makes it clearer what is happening:

```
n = int(input("Enter number of values: "))
for i in range(n):
    a = input("Enter value {} ".format(i+1))
    print("Value {0} was {1}".format(i+1, a))
```

The ouput from this was:

Enter number of values: 3
Enter value 1 1
Value 1 was 1
Enter value 2 1
Value 2 was 1
Enter value 3 2
Value 3 was 2

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing with the output printed by the loop.

If you enter `3` in the first `n = int(input(""))"` the loop will go from `0` to `2` (inclusive).

In every loop you ask for a new value of `a` and print it. So, after the first loop, you input `1` and it outputs `1` (because it prints it). In the second loop you input another `1` and it prints it. Finally you input a `2` and it also prints it.

First loop:

```
input: 1
output: 1
```

Second loop:

```
input: 1
output: 1
```

Third loop:

```
input: 2
output: 2
```

That's why if I run the following

```
>>> n = int(input(""))
3
>>> for i in range(n):
...     a = input("")
...     print a
...
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

I get 6 numbers (inputs and outputs). You can see this more clearly with the following example:

```
>>> n = int(input("Input: "))
Input: 3
>>> for i in range(n):
...     a = input("Input: ")
...     print "Output: " + str(a)
...
Input: 1
Output: 1
Input: 2
Output: 2
Input: 3
Output: 3
```